# AzureDevops webhook to jenkins fails on unauthorized access

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, webhooks

Recently i've updated jenkins to build 2.346.3 .

Since then Azure Devops webhook configured for triggering a build by the trigger "code push" fails with the following output:
`Failed Sent at: Wednesday, October 26, 2022 10:52:13 AM Message Jamal Hartnett pushed updates to Fabrikam-Fiber-Git:master. Error Message Unauthorized (401)`

I've tried to reach microsoft support to solve this..... the savior will not come from their side...

I am using a multibranch pipeline in jenkins.
The token is valid... as far as i see from the documents in jenkins their instructions is to use the "token" parameter in the URL but i don't see any "token" parameter in the URL azure devops sending the webhook to.
Any suggestions? .

I've tried to create new tokens , using CURL to see if the webhook works following the instructions in jenkins documentions which was succesfully performed without any error.

Comment: It could be a change from Jenkins side. you can try to append  ‘token=<Token>’ in the URL. Please refer to link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Jenkins-webhook-intergration-with-Azure-/10133603

Comment: Hi @wadezhou-MSFT, i've tried to do it .
But if i add the ‘token=<Token>’ in the base URL it will never react to the path the comes after it.
For Example:
https://jenkins.jenkins/?token=dasdsadsadsadsadsa/git/notifyCommit?url=<Path>&branch=<BranchName>

All the variable + URL Path that comes after "?token=<TOKEN>" does not considered as a path, only as parameters.
So this kind of "workaround" will not work .

Comment: According to the jenkins documentation: https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/, jenkins claims that the parameter “token” is required to perform the webhook successfully. And in the Developer community link i shared above, it can be resolved with token in the url, could you please have a double check? please try `&token=<token>` instead of `?`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. The fix is to update the server setting in the hook configuration in AZDO from `https://build.company.com` to `https://build.company.com/?token=<USERTOKEN>`.

[image: Settings in Azure DevOps]

The user token is one generated in a Jenkins user's profile section.